# What is the word for an existence which is " pioneer+guide+leader"?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

I am finding a word to describe a institute that is 'inventor of an idea + making that idea tangible & usable to human + leading this phenomenon'.

Comment: What's wrong with ***pioneer*** (or similar, such as ***trailblazer***)? Can you give an example context sentence where you want to use the word?

Comment: The institute could be **promoting** the phenomenon (although an invention isn't a phenomenon).

Comment: **Think tank**?

Comment: @FumbleFingers It is for an IT virtual project slogan. The sentence will be "A 'word that I am finding' Virtual Market".

Comment: You have four votes to close because your question lacks details. Your watch/clock question entered the Hot Network Questions which explains the thousands of views it attracted and the dozens of upvotes many answers attracted. But this time there are no upvotes, this time there's only one answer so the chances of your Q being closed is very likely UNLESS you add some context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The sample sentence I think the OP meant is “**Virtual Market ***is the ______ *** in commerce/shopping.” Shuvo, please add the example sentence where the word needed is in blank, IN the actual question and not in the comments. It will attract  more answers.

Comment: EDITED from an older comment. The sentence "A word that I am finding Virtual Market" is not idiomatic in Standard British or American English, people don't say: "I am finding [X]". It's either “*I am [**looking for**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/look_for)* [a] Virtual Market*”, which means  *searching*, or “*I have* [***found***](https://www.lexico.com/definition/find) [a] *Virtual Market*”. i.e. the speaker has discovered where the place is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In American industry, the term "Thought Leader" has started to emerge as exactly what you are describing. I've heard this term in private sector's like business and tech, and also in university settings. However, it's still new and comes across as pretentious.

Some other options that might work for you could include:

- trailblazer (like @FumbleFingers said)
- pioneer
- trendsetter
- innovator